# Create EaselJS sprite animation with SpriteStage (WebGL)

Tags: javascript, animation, webgl, sprite, easeljs

I have this sprite animation in EaselJS created with the classic Stage, here is the fiddle:

`Fiddle:` http://jsfiddle.net/6sygocvb/

EaselJS now has SpriteStage, which translates to WebGL and falls back to canvas if needed.

How do I create the example above with SpriteStage? Can you guys help me with a fiddle? Even though it is a very simple example, I just can't get it to work. I would be forever greatful if you can help me out with a working fiddle

Note: SpriteStage and SpriteContainer are in BETA and need to be included separately

https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/src/easeljs/display/SpriteContainer.js
https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/src/easeljs/display/SpriteStage.js

The reason behind this is that I want to create some sprite animations in WebGL (for obvious reasons) that fallback on canvas when WebGL is not supported. EaselJS is now offering a fast and simple solution with SpriteStage, but I'm open to other solutions as well

Any kind of help is highly appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Lanny, I have a fiddle with a somewhat working version of my sprite animation using SpriteStage, however, here it's not loading, all I see is a black background. it seems that it's not managing to load the background, any idea how to fix this?
His fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6sygocvb/1/

**UPDATE:**

Problem solved, thanks to Lanny, here is his [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/6sygocvb/5/) with loading the images before successfully. 
Also, a [separate thread](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/559#issuecomment-72154243) about loading images successfully with SpriteStage is on the CreateJS Community Forum

**SOLUTION:**
After many researches and with the awesome help from the CreateJS guys (Lanny & gskinner), I have created a repo with a setup that works well with SpriteStage.
The repo is [here](https://github.com/catalinberta/SpriteAnim/tree/master) and it contains a custom version of SpriteStage.js (thanks gskinner) that has a fix for loading the images before rendering them.

Thanks and enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an update fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/6sygocvb/1/

Note that all elements added to a SpriteContainer must have the same SpriteSheet.

The 2 bits I added are:

1) Change to SpriteStage. I also moved the canvas element to the HTML block of the fiddle:

```
var stage = new createjs.SpriteStage("canvas");
```

2) Create a SpriteContainer to add your Sprite to:

```
var container = new createjs.SpriteContainer(ss);
```

Hope that helps!

**[EDIT]**
Here is an updated fiddle using a power-of-2 image, and served from a CORS-enabled server.
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/6sygocvb/5/

Comment: Makes sense. Though the fiddle you have does not load the image and shows this warning + this error:

[.WebGLRenderingContext]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'
WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rect' of null                  
Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Hmm. Works in latest Chrome & Safari on OSX, and IE10. Firefox and Chrom on Windows throw a security warning, could be that its a cross-domain image. I changed the fiddle to load the image first, and it does help in a few places - but this demo would be better served with an image on the same domain.

Comment: I changed your image to be a power-of-2 image (512x512), and uploaded to a server that serves images with a CORS-header (making it safe for cross-domain loading). Here is the updated fiddle, it seems to work everywhere. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/6sygocvb/5/

Comment: You have saved the day!

Comment: We are currently testing a fix for SpriteStage that is caused by images that are not yet loaded. Currently you will get an error.  Should be fixed shortly. https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/559

Comment: Yes, I was the one who reported it and gskinner created the fix on another branch, I have updated this post with the solution. I made a repo with the solution including the fixed spritestage.js, you guys are awesome, thanks!